# How to get order count - SQL

Tags: mysql, count

I keep getting and SQL error (Unknown column 's01_Orders.id' in 'field list') every-time I try to run the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  SUM(agg.Total) as orderTotal,
  SUM(agg.NoShip) as orderTotalNoShip,
  COUNT(s01_Orders.id) as ordercount
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      o.total AS "Total",
      o.total - oc.amount AS "NoShip"
    FROM
      s01_Orders o
      JOIN s01_OrderDiscountTotals odt ON o.id = odt.order_id
      LEFT JOIN s01_OrderCharges oc ON o.id = oc.order_id
      AND oc.type = "SHIPPING"
      AND o.ship_cntry = "US"
    WHERE
      odt.coupon_id = "1395"
    GROUP BY
      odt.order_id
  ) agg
```

It works fine when I omit the following:

```
COUNT(s01_Orders.id) as ordercount
```

The s01_orders table and column exist - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because your subquery didn't contain `s01_Orders.id` column.What did you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The Subquery doesn't have the selection for s01_Orders.id

```
  SELECT
  SUM(agg.Total) as orderTotal,
  SUM(agg.NoShip) as orderTotalNoShip,
  ordercount
  FROM
 (
SELECT
  o.total AS "Total",
  o.total - oc.amount AS "NoShip",
  COUNT(o.id) as ordercount
FROM
  s01_Orders o
  JOIN s01_OrderDiscountTotals odt ON o.id = odt.order_id
  LEFT JOIN s01_OrderCharges oc ON o.id = oc.order_id
  AND oc.type = "SHIPPING"
  AND o.ship_cntry = "US"
WHERE
  odt.coupon_id = "1395"
GROUP BY
  odt.order_id
) agg
```

Try the above query, this has the selection of count and will work accordingly.

Comment: Well, it returns arbitrary ips and ordercounts, so I can't agree that it 'works fine'!

Comment: Then your internal subquery have some issue. Without, the table structure and result required, no one can provide the exact solution.

Comment: I'm not the OP.